# Symfony2, normal + rest authentication

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am having trouble figuring out how to structure my application.
It is currently a web application built using normal controllers, twig views etc. and using FOS user bundle for authentication. In this application it is possible to create entities that should be seen as a "mobile user"
Now I need an API for a mobile app where the "mobile users" should log in, but I cannot figure out how this authentication should be constructed.

Should I create a user in the user table along with the web app users? Is it possible to require a user to have a specific role to log in on the normal login page?

Or should I add a username and password column to the "mobile user" entity, and make a custom login for the api. But how is this accomplish? I am thinking of using angularjs in the mobile app if this has any impact on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you want the mobile user to have to login? Or should that user just be considered authenticated?

Comment: As there will be several mobile users they will have to login.

Comment: Does the mobile user HAVE to be a different Entity than other users?

Comment: Not really, I could make a one-to-one relation between the "special" entity and a user

Comment: In that case then why can you just send the mobile user to the same login page as the web user for authentication?

Comment: because the mobile user will not visit the website, but use an app (even though it will be built with phonegap and angular) that will communicate through an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions would be using [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle)

In this scenario you can have the same place you keep your users for both web app and mobile app. Users can authenticate using the same credentials in web and mobile app - but authentication for mobile app can be done through `ajax` call.

Thanks to [oAuth](http://oauth.net/) you don't keep login/password stored at your mobile app.
Bundle itself is written in a way that integrates with Symfony in perfect way.

To access different resources using different security you just configure different firewalls:

**security.yml**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
            security:   false
        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
        web_secured:
            pattern:   ^/
            stateless: true
            your_security_factory:      true
```

Check these resources for more info:

- [FOSOAuthServerBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)
- [step-by-step tutorial](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use a different user provider but you will need to configure a different firewall in security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    api_firewall:
        pattern: "^/api/"
        form_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            login_path: /api/login
```

Then you can still show your users a login form. Using angular, have it post to the check_path. Symfony uses cookies to store authentication information so you may have to configure angular to accept and pass those on subsequent request.

If you dont want to do that you could use an API key and write a custom authenticator implementing SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface